# PHP Imap Body encoding

Tags: php, imap

I have a question. I send out an E-Mail via "PHPMailer" Class. Then I answered with Outlook 2013 to this mail. Afterwords im Trying to read the Email via PHP with "imap_fetchbody". But I only get

```
PGh0bWwgeG1sbnM6dj0idXJuOnNjaGVtYXMtbWljcm9zb2Z0LWNvbTp2bWwiIHhtbG5zOm89InVy bjpzY2hlbWFzLW1pY3Jvc29mdC1jb206b2ZmaWNlOm9mZmljZSIgeG1sbnM6dz0idXJuOnNjaGVt YXMtbWljcm9zb2Z0LWNvbTpvZmZpY2U6d29yZCIgeG1sbnM6bT0iaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWlj cm9zb2Z0LmNvbS9vZmZpY2UvMjAwNC8xMi9vbW1sIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcv VFIvUkVDLWh0bWw0MCI+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxtZXRhIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIg Y29udGVudD0idGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04Ij4NCjxtZXRhIG5hbWU9IkdlbmVyYXRv ciIgY29udGVudD0iTWljcm9zb2Z0IFdvcmQgMTUgKGZpbHRlcmVkIG1lZGl1bSkiPg0KPCEtLVtp ZiAhbXNvXT48c3R5bGU+dlw6KiB7YmVoYXZpb3I6dXJsKCNkZWZhdWx0I1ZNTCk7fQ0Kb1w6KiB7 YmVoYXZpb3I6dXJsKCNkZWZhdWx0I1ZNTCk7fQ0Kd1w6KiB7YmVoYXZpb3I6dXJsKCNkZWZhdWx0 I1ZNTCk7fQ0KLnNoYXBlIHtiZWhhdmlvcjp1cmwoI2RlZmF1bHQjVk1MKTt9DQo8L3N0eWxlPjwh W2VuZGlmXS0tPjxzdHlsZT48IS0tD[...]
```

Stuff like this - I tried many decoding options in the imap_fetchbody function, but I am not getting it - this is my code:

```js
$server='{IPADDRESS:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$adresse='cloud@MYDOMAIN';
$password='MYPASSWORD';
$mbox = imap_open($server, $adresse, $password, OP_READONLY, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'PLAIN')) or die(var_dump(imap_errors()));

$no = 1;
$headers = imap_headers($mbox);
$text = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $no, 1);
 
for($i = 0; $i < count($headers); ++$i)
{
 
$string = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $i+1, 1);
echo $string;
  
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. It seems that those messages come with different Mime Types, etc. So this function helps to find the mime type and offers an easy "getBody" function - see this page:

https://www.sitepoint.com/exploring-phps-imap-library-1/